# How to remove search bar background?

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I want to remove search bar background and I have tried the following code in custom search bar subclass:

```
-(void)didAddSubview:(UIView *)subview
{
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")])
    {
        subview.alpha=0;

    }
}
```

every thing ok but when click on search bar or cancel search the background color set to black
any one knows how to remove this background color?

Comment: searchbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
searchbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

I used this code in one of my applications to remove the background and added my own background image

```
[[searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
     UIImageView *searchImage=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 319.0, 44.0)];
    [searchImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchbg.png"]];
    [searchBar insertSubview:searchImage atIndex:1];
```

This may help you.

Comment: ok but it doesn't change it's background when you click cancel or when you click on search bar

Comment: does it remove the background or not ?? I so you can add a transparent image in place of "searchbg.png" in my code.